# Unable to get session in nextAuth

Tags: reactjs, session, next.js, next-auth

I was trying to learn nextAuth using some tutorial videos on youtube. And I stumbled on a problem.
This is my `app/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",

      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch("/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: credentials?.username,
            password: credentials?.password,
          }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});
```

My login page is (whose path is `app/login.js` is

```
"use client";
import style from "./login.module.css";
import username from "./username-icon.png";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faUser } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faLock } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
function Login() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    username: null,
    password: null,
  });

  function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "name": {
        return {
          username: action.name,
          password: state.password,
        };
      }

      case "pass": {
        return {
          username: state.username,
          password: action.password,
        };
      }
    }
  }

  async function submitHandler(event) {
      const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      username: state.username,
      password: state.password,
      redirect: true,
      callbackUrl: "/admin",
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className={style.main}>
      <div className={style.mainform}>
        <div className={style.login}>Login</div>

        <div>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className={style.nameborder}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faUser}
                 style={{
                  color: "rgba(85,86,88,0.8)",
                  marginRight: "15px",
                  fontSize: "20px",
                }}
              />
              <input
                className={style.name}
                name="name"
                placeholder="Username"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  dispatch({
                    type: "name",
                    name: e.target.value,
                  });
                }}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className={style.passborder}>
             <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faLock}
                style={{
                  color: "rgba(85,86,88,0.8)",
                   marginRight: "15px",
                  fontSize: "20px",
                }}
              />
              <input
                className={style.password}
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  dispatch({
                    type: "pass",
                    password: e.target.value,
                  });
                }}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <input
              type="submit"
              name="login"
              value="Login"
              className={style.loginbutton}
            ></input>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

This is my root page whose path ia `app/page.js` where I tried to excess session

```
"use client";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(useSession());

  return (
    <div>
      {session?.user ? (
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>signout</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => signIn()}>signin</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also wrapped `Provide.js` with `SessionProvider` and `layout.js` with `Provider`

When I open the site on the app on the browser it shows following error

```
:3000/api/auth/session:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 
of 404 (Not Found)

[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] https://next- 
auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE 
"... is not valid JSON

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't know whether the tutorial went wrong or I. I have been stuck in this problem from 2 days. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct location of the NextAuth configuration file under the `app` router is `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js` and it is expected to export `GET` and `POST` named exports.

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // TODO: implement authentication
        if (credentials?.username === "jsmith") {
          return {
            name: "J Smith",
            email: "jsmith@example.com",
          };
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

See configuration documentation here - https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app

Also, you do not have to use the reducer to maintain the login form state. It can simplified as follows.

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Login() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = new FormData(event.target);

    const username = form.get("username");
    const password = form.get("password");

    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      username,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (!result.error) {
      router.push("/");
    }

    // TODO: handle error
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input required name="username" type="text" placeholder="jsmith" />
      <input required name="password" type="password" />

      <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is a working [example](https://k8wr5v-3000.csb.app) with [source code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-76522472-k8wr5v?file=%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Fpage.js).

P.S. Also, do not forget to specify `NEXTAUTH_URL` and `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` environment variables in the `.env` file.

Comment: Actually this didn't work unitl I initialized next app with .eslintrc.json.  Can you please tell why

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs 13 APP Directory, api are exposed through `route.ts` file. Firstly, your auth route is not correctly configured. It should look like this :

`api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

In your route.ts file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
const handler =  NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",

      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch("/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: credentials?.username,
            password: credentials?.password,
          }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: The above code snippet won't work since the `app` API routes are expected to export named exports (GET, POST, etc.). Please correct your answer according to the documentation - https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app

Comment: @IgorDanchenko can you please provide me the solution. I checked the documentation but I got completely lost on it.

Comment: @IgorDanchenko Thanks for correcting. While answering i was more concern around the api route fiile structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";


const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!
        })
        // ...add more providers here
    ],
    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET!
    },
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET!,

})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

There are some changes in providers but the main logics remains the same.